# Problem with .then off a javascript async function

Tags: javascript, promise

I ran into a weird problem with a .then off an asyc function's promise.
I call to a function to check the user's google id against my database to see if they have an account on the network.

```
Login(DecodedGoogleCredentials.sub).then((localID)=> {//Login returns a promise with the local id for the database

             console.log(localID);//used to confirm id
             sessionStorage.setItem("CurrentUserID", localID);//set for refresh

             setID(localID);//set to recall App
             setLogin(true);//set to ensure it will be recalled

       });//end of Login().then(()=>{});
```

In my asnc function, I get the local id I expect, but when I check it with `console.log(localID);` in my .then, it writes a result of undefined.

Here is the async function:

```
async function Login(GoogleID) {//Called from App()
    
    const idQuery = query(idRef, where("id", "==", GoogleID.toString()));//build query for user's id
    const idDoc = await getDocs(idQuery);//get doc found in query. There should only be one
    
    var userFound = false;//user is not found
    
    idDoc.forEach((doc) => {//loop through docs

        userFound = true;//user is found  
        const localID = doc.data().localID;
        console.log(localID)
        try {
            return localID;
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
        
    });
    //there is no user so far
    if (userFound==false) {//create new user if user is not found
        
       return await CreateUser(GoogleID);//create the login
    }
}//end of Login(id)
```

The `console.log(localID)` here works perfectly and writes the value that I expect. Anyone know why I'm getting a different result in my .then function?

Answer:

Thanks everyone for your help. The problem stemmed from me returning from a foreach.
here is what my new code looks like, which functions correctly

```
async function Login(GoogleID) {//Called from App()
    
    const idQuery = query(idRef, where("id", "==", GoogleID.toString()));//build query for user's id
    const idDoc = await getDocs(idQuery);//get doc found in query. There should only be one

    var foundDoc;
    idDoc.forEach((doc) => {//loop through docs
       foundDoc = doc
    });
    if (foundDoc != null) {
        const localID = foundDoc.data().localID;
        
       
            return localID;
        
    }
   else {//create new user if user is not found
        
       return CreateUser(GoogleID);//create the login
    }
}//end of Login(id)
```

Comment: you return from callback for forEach, not from the function

Comment: Indeed. Change that `foreach` to a `for (let x of idDoc)` and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement in the `forEach` loop exists the function you are passing to it, and not the main `Login` function.

Also the `try`/`catch` around it is useless, since `return` followed by a variable will never throw.

Consider using `Array.prototype.find` instead:

```js
async function login(id) {
    const idQuery = query(idRef, where("id", "==", id.toString()));
    const idDoc = await getDocs(idQuery);
    const foundID = idDoc.find((doc) => doc.data().localID);
    if (foundID) {
        return foundID;
    }
    return CreateUser(id);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to check truthy of `localID` with `Array::find()`

Comment: also you don't need `if`: `return idDoc.find((doc) => doc.data().localID) || CreateUser(id);`

Answer (score 0):

You return from the callback for `forEach()`, not from the function. You could fix:

```
return idDoc[0]?.data().localID ?? CreateUser(GoogleID);
```

Here we expect that idDoc contains objects. If there's no an object with index `0` (`dDoc[0]?.`) then we create a new user.

You don't need `Array::forEach()` here since you check the first element only - there's nothing to iterate to find an array item beyond the index `0`.

Also you don't need `return await` since it's waste of time to wait a promise that will be waited or even discarded later, not good for  performance potentially.

Also don't use `var` - it's legacy and buggy.